# Does every noetherian ring inject into the product of its localizations at primes?

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a noetherian ring. There is a natural map $R\rightarrow \prod_p R_p$, where $R_p$ is the localizations of $R$ at prime ideals $p$ of $R$.

Must this map be injective?

(I'm happy to consider the case where $R$ is moreover finitely generated over a Dedekind domain)

(I can show that the kernel must be contained in the nilradical)

Comment: Let $K$ be the kerne. If $p$ is a prime, what is $K_p$?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez It doesn't seem so easy to describe to me..., other than that it's the kernel of the map $R_p \rightarrow \prod_q R_q\otimes_R R_p$...

Comment: Well, if $K$ is in the kernel of your map, it is also in the kernel of $R\to R_p$.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Right, so from this I can see that any $x\in K$ must have the property that for every prime $p$, there is a $y_p\in R-p$ such that $xy_p = 0$. Since these are prime ideals, this implies that $x$ must lie in every prime ideal, but I don't see why it needs to be 0.

Comment: So, what is the localization $K_p$?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Ah, okay, so I suppose all the stalks of $\tilde{K}$ are zero, and hence $K = 0$. I guess we're not even using the noetherian assumption here?

Comment: Please do write a complete answer to the question, so that it does not remain open forever.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes - the map must be injective.

Indeed, let $K$ be the kernel of the map, and let $x\in K$. This means, that for every prime $p$, there is a $y_p\in R - p$ satisfying $xy_p = 0$ in $R$.

Viewing $K$ as an $R$-module, this implies that the localization $K\otimes_R R_p = 0$ for every prime $p$ of $R$, but we know from the theory of quasicoherent sheaves that the modules $K\otimes_R R_p$ are precisely the stalks of the sheaf $\tilde{K}$, and a sheaf is 0 if and only if its stalks are zero, and hence $K = 0$.

Alternatively, the fact that $K = 0$ follows from the results of https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0546

Moreover, when $R$ is noetherian, one gets an injective map to the product of the localizations at the associated primes of $R$.